# Choose values for n and x so that the value of $n\sqrt x$ is

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

A whole number
A negative number
A rational number
An irrational number

Looking back at your choices for $n$ and $x$, list any restrictions on the values in each case.

*Please guys help me with this. I have a test tomorrow and this is not explained in the textbooks!!!

Comment: What's the problem? A whole number will result in multiplying a number from 1 to $\infty$ by a perfect square, or 0 with anything. A negative number where $n$ must be negative and $x$ can be any positive real number.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Ok Andrew...for that I have this for my whole number..2=n x=64..=8. For the negative number I have this.....2=n, x=-64=-8

Comment: Is that right? Also, how do I get the rational and irrational numbers?

Comment: The square root of -64 is not -8.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this naturally. $n \sqrt{x}$ will be a whole number if $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $\sqrt{x} \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow x$ is a perfect square (4, 9, 25, etc). It it will be a negative number if $n < 0$, since $Re(\sqrt{x}) \geq 0, \forall x$. I will let to you to decide when it is a rational or irrational number. Think you can take it from here?